# Is it possible to detect an ajax request with Apache 2.4 for a mod_rewrite rule?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, ajax

Is it possible?

Trying to move my script security to the server-level.

With PHP, just check if `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` is set to `XMLHttpRequest` (jQuery added).

I guess maybe a better question is, how can I add the `X-Requested-With` request header to a variable I can check with a mod_rewrite `RewriteCond`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting the `X-Requested-With` HTTP request header as part of the "AJAX request" (as would be implied if you are seeing `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` in PHP) then you can check this header directly with mod_rewrite.

For example, to serve a 403 Forbidden for any requests to the `/scripts/` directory that do not have an `X-Forwarded-With` HTTP header set to `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Requested-With} !=XMLHttpRequest
RewriteRule ^/?scripts/ - [F]
```